# 4 levels of nested Json, how to flatten?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am trying to [flatten](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) json with 4 levels of nested arrays. What is the best way to flatten this data, without having to flatten it 4 times?

Data example, staged:

```
{
    "sample": {
        "someitem": {
            "thesearecool": [
                {
                    "neat": "wow"
                },
                {
                    "neat": "tubular"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I think this works for the first flatten, but is there some way to flatten it two more times, so that each value is in a different column?

```
select src:sample::string, src:someitem::string, value
from
raw_source
, lateral flatten( input => src:sample )
```

Source: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Lateral-Join-Tutorial

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you would expect the results to look like? Do you expect "wow" and "tabular" to be in separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to list the values of the neat values?

```
with raw_source as (select parse_json('{
    "sample": {
        "someitem": {
            "thesearecool": [
                {
                    "neat": "wow"
                },
                {
                    "neat": "tubular"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}') c)
select f.value:neat as neat
from
raw_source 
, lateral flatten( input => c, path => 'sample.someitem.thesearecool'  ) f;
```

In this case, you can use path parameter.